# Menu Order updating automatically

Tags: sql

I have a custom post type with page-attributes declared so I am able to put in a menu_order number/field for sorting them via menu order. This all works as expected except this next issue.

I reset all the custom post type menu_order fields to 0 (int) with sql. I then refresh the site. Wordpress then auto-increments menu order instead of leaving them all at 0. Does anyone know why this behaviour would happen?

Here is the sql for resetting all menu_order items to 0.

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET menu_order=0 WHERE post_type='custom_post_type'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't believe that what you describe is default WP behaviour. Are you sure you don't have any hooks affecting it?

Comment: Hmm, I thought maybe so as I agree with you. I tried a new theme but still the same issue is happening. Maybe it's the plugin. I just wanted to make sure it wasn't something else i was missing. Thank you in advance!